# chrome caches old styles on react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The file setup I have to work with has a bug where sometimes styles are not updated or styles from previous versions are still applied to the app.

What exactly happens:

1. I update a style (say change a color from blue to red)
2. it gets updated in the browser (item is now red)
3. I restart the server
4. The style is back to the version before I updated it (item is blue again)
5. Sometimes after refreshing the window once or twice, the new style gets applied (sometimes item is red again)
6. Sometimes after working on other parts of the project for a while, the bug disappears

I haven't found a pattern for when it happens. It happens with both inline styles and styles in my scss files.

What I've tried:

1. forbid chrome from keeping data from 'localhost:3000'
2. disable server-side rendering in my app
3. rebuilding my bundle
4. happens in dev and production build

The setup is slightly outdated but unfortunately, I have to work with it.

relevant packages are

```
"webpack": "^4.25.1",
"react": "^16.8.4",
"node-sass": "^4.10.0"
```

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. I assume you have disable cache checked in chrom dev tools?

Comment: @GifCo yes, in dev tools and for localhost in general

Comment: Do you have a service worker installed??? If so try removing it every time you make an update and see if that fixes things

Comment: Are you using Create React App? Then you can [`unregister` the service worker](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2715#issuecomment-312666604).

Comment: I don't have service workers set up, the setup is built uppon react boilerplate I believe but it's not my setup so I'm not 100% sure

Comment: have you tried doing `ctl + shift + R` after changing the css values? it does seem like a browser issue to me